# Cant Bringup on turtlebot3 with roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, robotics

I am trying to bring up turtlebot3 but every time i run `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch` on Turtlebot i get this error:

```
[RLException: [turtlebot3_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_bringup] nor is [turtlebot3_bringup] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.]
```

I did run `roscore` on a remote PC and it worked before running the above-mentioned command on turtlebot3. I have tried many solutions but none worked for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I TRIED TO UNINSTALL AND REINSTALL ROS TOO BUT NO SUCCESS WITH BRINGUP.

Answer (score 1):

That package does not come directly with a ros install; you have to install it yourself either via apt or from source.

The easiest way is to run `sudo apt install ros-<your_distro>-turtlebot3-bringup`. Then just source `/opt` and run the command.

Comment: i tried sudo apt install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-bringup, but it gives me unable to locate package error

Comment: @samanawhatever have you actually installed ROS on that machine and have it connected to the internet? You mention a PC and Pi, do both have ROS installed?

Comment: yes, i both remote pc and pi are connected to the same wifi network and both have kinetic ROS installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to run `source devel/setup.bash`?

You need to run it every time you launch a new terminal.

Comment: do I run it on a remote PC or PI?

Comment: on your raspberry pi